# Installing/using quadprog in Python

Tags: python, quadprog

Has anyone used quadprog in Python before? I tried installing and importing it, and it was succesful, but when I try to use it I get this message:

```
'module' object is not callable
```

Installed with:

```
pip install quadprog
import quadprog
```